# How do you show that there exists a set N a subset of (0,1) that is not Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: functional-programming, analysis

How do you show that there exists a set N in (0,1) that is not Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: This question is not about programming. https://math.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic.